# Dijkstra path (not only distance)

Tags: prolog, logic-programming

I have the code that calculates the minimum distance of Dijkstra path. Can you help me edit my code in order to not only print the minimum distance, but the full path too?

```
% min_dist(+Graph,+Start,-MinDist)
min_dist(Graph,Start,MinDist):-
   dijkstra(Graph,[],[Start-0],MinDist).

edge(g(Es,Vs),V1,V2,Value):-
   member(e(V1,V2,Value),Vs) ;
   member(e(V2,V1,Value),Vs).

neighbourhood(Graph,V,NB):-
   setof(V1-E,edge(Graph,V,V1,E),NB).

% dijkstra(+Graph,+ClosedVertices,+OpenVertices,-Distances)
dijkstra(_,MinDist,[],MinDist).
dijkstra(Graph,Closed,Open,MinDist):-
   choose_v(Open,V-D,RestOpen),
   neighbourhood(Graph,V,NB),  % NB is a list of adjacent vertices+distance to V
   diff(NB,Closed,NewNB),
   merge(NewNB,RestOpen,D,NewOpen),
   dijkstra(Graph,[V-D|Closed],NewOpen,MinDist).

% choose_v(+OpenVertices,-VertexToExpand,-RestOpenVertices)
choose_v([H|T],MinV,Rest):-
   choose_minv(T,H,MinV,Rest).
choose_minv([],MinV,MinV,[]).
choose_minv([H|T],M,MinV,[H2|Rest]):-
   H=V1-D1, M=V-D,
   (D1<D -> NextM=H,H2=M
          ; NextM=M,H2=H),
   choose_minv(T,NextM,MinV,Rest).

% diff(+ListOfVertices,+Closed,-ListOfNonClosedVertices)
diff([],_,[]).
diff([H|T],Closed,L):-
   H=V-D,
   (member(V-_,Closed) -> L=NewT ; L=[H|NewT]),
   diff(T,Closed,NewT).

% merge(+ListOfVertices,+OldOpenVertices,-AllOpenVertices)
merge([],L,_,L).
merge([V1-D1|T],Open,D,NewOpen):-
   (remove(Open,V1-D2,RestOpen)
      -> VD is min(D2,D+D1)
       ; RestOpen=Open,VD is D+D1),
   NewOpen=[V1-VD|SubOpen],
   merge(T,RestOpen,D,SubOpen).

remove([H|T],H,T).
remove([H|T],X,[H|NT]):-
   H\=X,
   remove(T,X,NT).
```

Thanks!
EDIT: I have edited my code because I have forgot to add the neighbourhood and edge predicates.

Comment: 'your' code has singletons, it's improbable it's working. At least, add an example of query, to see the graph format ...

Comment: Singletons ( V1, V in "choose_minv" and D in "diff" ) can be replaced by _ . They are not errors.

Answer (score 1):

Nice source, well organized and well commented.

I suggest you to modify your "merge" statements in order to, not only update the minimal distances, but include a third field with the vertice that gives this minimum.

(warning: comment for theses statements lacks one argument).

Something like:

```
merge([V1-D1|T],Open,V-D-_,[V1-VD-O|SubOpen]):-
   (remove(Open,V1-D2-O2,RestOpen)
      -> ( D2<D+D1 -> VD=D2, O=O2 ; VD is D+D1, O=V)
      ; RestOpen=Open,VD is D+D1,O=V),
   merge(T,RestOpen,D,SubOpen).
```

that means you must adapt all remainder to pass terms of the form "Vertice-Distance-Origin".

Comment: thank you for your answer, but can you please review my first post? I edited it, because I forgot to add the neighbourhood and edge predicates ... And btw, here is how I run my program:  min_dist(g([a, b, c, d], [e(a, b, 3), e(b, d, 4), e(a, d, 2), e(c, d, 1)]), a, X).
And the result will be: X = [c-3, b-3, d-2, a-0]. Now, how can I do to print the path too?

Comment: No change in the comment, use term Vertex-Distance-Origin. The result of "min_dist" will be all vertex with its minimal distance and the previous vertice. At the end, go back from last node to start.

Comment: thank you @pasaba ; Changing my merge predicate with yours, doesn't return me anymore the list, it returns false

Comment: You must adapt remainder code. Old one used terms in the form Vertex-Distance, new one is Vertex-Distance-Previous_Vertex.